# How to get CSS colour value using Xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is this script I tried.

1. How can we identify the element with and get CSS color value using this XPath?
2. What is the meaning of this Xpath?

   ```
   package mypackage;    
   import org.openqa.selenium.*;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;    
   import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
   import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

   public class myclass {

           public static void main(String[] args) {
           String baseUrl = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/";
           WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

           driver.get(baseUrl);
           WebElement link_Home = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Home"));
           WebElement td_Home = driver
           .findElement(By
           .xpath("//html/body/div"
           + "/table/tbody/tr/td"
           + "/table/tbody/tr/td"
           + "/table/tbody/tr/td"
           + "/table/tbody/tr"));

           Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
           Action mouseOverHome = builder
           .moveToElement(link_Home)
           .build();

           String bgColor = td_Home.getCssValue("background-color");
           System.out.println("Before hover: " + bgColor);
           mouseOverHome.perform();
           bgColor = td_Home.getCssValue("background-color");
           System.out.println("After hover: " + bgColor);
           driver.quit();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you be more specific please as what exactly do you want to know ? Because, a simple google search will tell you all about xpath.

Answer (score 1):

To get CSS colour value using Xpath, you can use this code:

```
String color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath")).getCssValue("color");
```

**It will return output in "RGBA" format as: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)".**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is of course not an efficient way to write `xpath`. I tested your `xpath` and it returns 9 different matches. To find `css` color value of a specific element your `xpath` or any other **selector** needs to be very specific. After that `getCssValue` and with any valid property name such as `color, background-color` and such will return you desire value. Your code looks fine to me except the selector. Additionally, if you want to find css values for all elements that `xpath` retuning you might want to loop and print the values of each. [image]